# pandas group by date, assign value to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, jupyter-notebook

I have a DataFrame with columns = ['date','id','value'], where id represents different products. Assume that we have n products. I am looking to create a new dataframe with columns = ['date', 'valueid1' ..,'valueidn'], where the values are assigned to the corresponding date-row if they exist, a NaN is assigned as value if they don't. Many thanks

Comment: you are looking for the [`pivot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function. You can find more information about the usage in the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [120]: df
Out[120]:
        date  id  value
0 2001-01-01   1     10
1 2001-01-01   2     11
2 2001-01-01   3     12
3 2001-01-02   3     20
4 2001-01-03   1     20
5 2001-01-04   2     30
```

you can use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method:

```
In [121]: df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='id', values='value')
Out[121]:
id             1     2     3
date
2001-01-01  10.0  11.0  12.0
2001-01-02   NaN   NaN  20.0
2001-01-03  20.0   NaN   NaN
2001-01-04   NaN  30.0   NaN
```

or

```
In [122]: df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='id', values='value', fill_value=0)
Out[122]:
id           1   2   3
date
2001-01-01  10  11  12
2001-01-02   0   0  20
2001-01-03  20   0   0
2001-01-04   0  30   0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='date', columns='id', values='value')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=5),
                   'id':[4,5,6,4,5],
                   'value':[7,8,9,1,2]})

print (df)
        date  id  value
0 2017-01-01   4      7
1 2017-01-02   5      8
2 2017-01-03   6      9
3 2017-01-04   4      1
4 2017-01-05   5      2

df = df.pivot(index='date', columns='id', values='value')
#alternative solution
#df = df.set_index(['date','id'])['value'].unstack()
print (df)
id            4    5    6
date                     
2017-01-01  7.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-02  NaN  8.0  NaN
2017-01-03  NaN  NaN  9.0
2017-01-04  1.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-05  NaN  2.0  NaN
```

but if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

is necessary use aggregating function like `mean`, `sum`, ... with `groupby` or [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02',
                          '2017-01-03','2017-01-05','2017-01-05'],
                   'id':[4,5,6,4,4],
                   'value':[7,8,9,1,2]})

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
print (df)
        date  id  value
0 2017-01-01   4      7
1 2017-01-02   5      8
2 2017-01-03   6      9
3 2017-01-05   4      1 <- duplicity 2017-01-05   4
4 2017-01-05   4      2 <- duplicity 2017-01-05   4

df = df.groupby(['date', 'id'])['value'].mean().unstack()
#alternative solution (another answer same as groupby only slowier in big df)
#df = df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='id', values='value', aggfunc='mean')

print (df)
id            4    5    6
date                     
2017-01-01  7.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-02  NaN  8.0  NaN
2017-01-03  NaN  NaN  9.0
2017-01-05  1.5  NaN  NaN <- 1.5 is mean (1 + 2)/2
```